# How to add a description to a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know that \d+ lists the tables and their descriptions such as:

```
                           List of relations
 Schema |      Name       | Type  |  Owner  |    Size    | Description
--------+-----------------+-------+---------+------------+-------------
 public | table1          | table | me      | 123 kB     |
 public | table2          | table | me      | 123 kB     |
 public | table3          | view  | me      | 123 kB     |
 public | table4          | table | me      | 123 kB     | some description
 public | table5          | table | me      | 123 kB     |
 public | table6          | table | me      | 123 kB     | another description
(6 rows)
```

I want to know how to alter a description or write one if one does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
comment on table table1 is 'This is a new description';
comment on table table4 is 'This is a changed description';
```

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html